# Unable to fetch data from Scala Map inside a Scala iterator

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark scala dataframe which is converted as an Iterator.

```
val rows = df.toLocalIterator.asScala
```

then a Map of records(documents) from MongoDB which is converted as Map(String, (String, Int))

```
val recordsMap = dbRecords.map( ***some logic here to convert Seq of Doc to Map(String, (String,Int)) ***).flatten.toMap
```

dbRecords is a Scala Sequence of Documents...

My task is to fetch the record from Map(mongodb) based on the key from Spark Dataframe. I tried below code:

```
rows.grouped(batchSize) foreach { rows =>
    val reqs = rows.map { r =>
        val key = r.getAs[String]("id")
        val idDetailsInMongo = recordsMap.get(key)
        println(idDetailsInMongo) // Always giving me None
        ...
        ...
        some other code.
    }
}
```

I tried fetching the data from outside the Iterator of rows, I am getting data
(just before the line rows.grouped(batchSize))

```
val key = "1234"
println(recordsMap.get(key)) //got the desired result, ie Some(("val1","val2")
```

Even more strange is, if I hardcode the value of key and fetch Map data inside the iterator I am getting the correct output.

```
rows.grouped(batchSize) foreach { rows =>
        val reqs = rows.map { r =>
            val key = r.getAs[String]("id")
            val idDetailsInMongo = recordsMap.get("1234")
            println(idDetailsInMongo) // In this case, getting result for id:1234
```

I am completely stuck, I faced the same issue with Seq[Document], using `Seq.find()`.
Hence I tried converting Seq to Map and used `Map.get()` but no difference.